# Rounding Decimal

Tags: decimal, swift3, nsdecimalnumber

In `NSDecimalNumber` there's a method to round the number, I.E.

```
let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)

let example: NSDecimalNumber = 1.345
let rounded: NSDecimalNumber = example.rounding(accordingToBehavior: handler)
```

Now I've switched to `Decimal` and it doesn't seem to have the method to round the number like `NSDecimalNumber` has. Should I cast it to `NSDecimalNumber` and cast it back to `Decimal` just to round things up or is there a better and more elegant way of rounding a `Decimal`?

EDIT: made a better example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Decimal` has become an easy and concise way to handle decimal numbers in Swift 3, but if you want to control some rounding mode or rounding scale, you need to use `NSDecimal...` functions.

[Foundation Functions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1613024-foundation_functions)

See **Decimals** part.

[`NSDecimalRound(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1412204-nsdecimalround)

```
var dexample: Decimal = 1.345
var drounded: Decimal = Decimal()
NSDecimalRound(&drounded, &dexample, 2, .plain)
print(drounded) //->1.35
```

Comment: It seems similar to what I've done in my example except this looks a bit shorter. Too bad there's no built in option to round a `Decimal`. I'll leave the answer unmarked for a short time, if there's no other alternative then I'll mark this as answered, thanks!

Comment: @HennyLee, IMO, this may be sort of not-yet thing (at least I hope so), as writing an extension for `Decimal` including `rounding(...)` is super-easy. To accelerate Apple's movement toward it, better send a [feature request](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Answer (score -2):

It's simple

```
let x = 1.23556789
let y = Int(round(x))
print(y)
```

Comment: In your example, `x` is a `Double`. If `x` is a `Decimal` it won't work. Nevertheless I should have been more clear with my example. Using `Int` would round up without any decimals.

Comment: If you need decimal part you can use "let x = 1.23556789
let y = Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
print(y)"

Comment: But I don't think using `Double` is a good way of handling decimals, especially when it comes to currency. Thanks for the help though.